# ProtoBuf tutorial: "AddressBook does not implement "github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto".Message (ProtoMessage method has pointer receiver)"

Tags: go

I'm trying to follow along with this tutorial on ProtoBufs: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/gotutorial. I have the following project structure:

```
.
├── addressbook
│   ├── addressbook.pb.go
│   └── addressbook.proto
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── main.go
```

where `addressbook.proto` is

```
syntax = "proto3";
package addressbook;

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message Person {
    string name = 1;
    int32 id = 2;
    string email = 3;

    enum PhoneType {
        MOBILE = 0;
        HOME = 1;
        WORK = 2;
    }

    message PhoneNumber {
        string number = 1;
        PhoneType type = 2;
    }

    repeated PhoneNumber phones = 4;

    google.protobuf.Timestamp last_updated = 5;
}

message AddressBook {
    repeated Person people = 1;
}
```

and the auto-generated (with `protoc addressbook.proto --go-out=.`) `addressbook.pb.go` reads

```
// Code generated by protoc-gen-go. DO NOT EDIT.
// source: addressbook.proto

package addressbook

import (
    fmt "fmt"
    proto "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
    timestamp "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp"
    math "math"
)

// Reference imports to suppress errors if they are not otherwise used.
var _ = proto.Marshal
var _ = fmt.Errorf
var _ = math.Inf

// This is a compile-time assertion to ensure that this generated file
// is compatible with the proto package it is being compiled against.
// A compilation error at this line likely means your copy of the
// proto package needs to be updated.
const _ = proto.ProtoPackageIsVersion3 // please upgrade the proto package

type Person_PhoneType int32

const (
    Person_MOBILE Person_PhoneType = 0
    Person_HOME   Person_PhoneType = 1
    Person_WORK   Person_PhoneType = 2
)

var Person_PhoneType_name = map[int32]string{
    0: "MOBILE",
    1: "HOME",
    2: "WORK",
}

var Person_PhoneType_value = map[string]int32{
    "MOBILE": 0,
    "HOME":   1,
    "WORK":   2,
}

func (x Person_PhoneType) String() string {
    return proto.EnumName(Person_PhoneType_name, int32(x))
}

func (Person_PhoneType) EnumDescriptor() ([]byte, []int) {
    return fileDescriptor_1eb1a68c9dd6d429, []int{0, 0}
}

type Person struct {
    Name                 string                `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=name,proto3" json:"name,omitempty"`
    Id                   int32                 `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=id,proto3" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Email                string                `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=email,proto3" json:"email,omitempty"`
    Phones               []*Person_PhoneNumber `protobuf:"bytes,4,rep,name=phones,proto3" json:"phones,omitempty"`
    LastUpdated          *timestamp.Timestamp  `protobuf:"bytes,5,opt,name=last_updated,json=lastUpdated,proto3" json:"last_updated,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{}              `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte                `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32                 `json:"-"`
}

func (m *Person) Reset()         { *m = Person{} }
func (m *Person) String() string { return proto.CompactTextString(m) }
func (*Person) ProtoMessage()    {}
func (*Person) Descriptor() ([]byte, []int) {
    return fileDescriptor_1eb1a68c9dd6d429, []int{0}
}

func (m *Person) XXX_Unmarshal(b []byte) error {
    return xxx_messageInfo_Person.Unmarshal(m, b)
}
func (m *Person) XXX_Marshal(b []byte, deterministic bool) ([]byte, error) {
    return xxx_messageInfo_Person.Marshal(b, m, deterministic)
}
func (m *Person) XXX_Merge(src proto.Message) {
    xxx_messageInfo_Person.Merge(m, src)
}
func (m *Person) XXX_Size() int {
    return xxx_messageInfo_Person.Size(m)
}
func (m *Person) XXX_DiscardUnknown() {
    xxx_messageInfo_Person.DiscardUnknown(m)
}

var xxx_messageInfo_Person proto.InternalMessageInfo

func (m *Person) GetName() string {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Name
    }
    return ""
}

func (m *Person) GetId() int32 {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Id
    }
    return 0
}

func (m *Person) GetEmail() string {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Email
    }
    return ""
}

func (m *Person) GetPhones() []*Person_PhoneNumber {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Phones
    }
    return nil
}

func (m *Person) GetLastUpdated() *timestamp.Timestamp {
    if m != nil {
        return m.LastUpdated
    }
    return nil
}

type Person_PhoneNumber struct {
    Number               string           `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=number,proto3" json:"number,omitempty"`
    Type                 Person_PhoneType `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=type,proto3,enum=addressbook.Person_PhoneType" json:"type,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{}         `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte           `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32            `json:"-"`
}

func (m *Person_PhoneNumber) Reset()         { *m = Person_PhoneNumber{} }
func (m *Person_PhoneNumber) String() string { return proto.CompactTextString(m) }
func (*Person_PhoneNumber) ProtoMessage()    {}
func (*Person_PhoneNumber) Descriptor() ([]byte, []int) {
    return fileDescriptor_1eb1a68c9dd6d429, []int{0, 0}
}

func (m *Person_PhoneNumber) XXX_Unmarshal(b []byte) error {
    return xxx_messageInfo_Person_PhoneNumber.Unmarshal(m, b)
}
func (m *Person_PhoneNumber) XXX_Marshal(b []byte, deterministic bool) ([]byte, error) {
    return xxx_messageInfo_Person_PhoneNumber.Marshal(b, m, deterministic)
}
func (m *Person_PhoneNumber) XXX_Merge(src proto.Message) {
    xxx_messageInfo_Person_PhoneNumber.Merge(m, src)
}
func (m *Person_PhoneNumber) XXX_Size() int {
    return xxx_messageInfo_Person_PhoneNumber.Size(m)
}
func (m *Person_PhoneNumber) XXX_DiscardUnknown() {
    xxx_messageInfo_Person_PhoneNumber.DiscardUnknown(m)
}

var xxx_messageInfo_Person_PhoneNumber proto.InternalMessageInfo

func (m *Person_PhoneNumber) GetNumber() string {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Number
    }
    return ""
}

func (m *Person_PhoneNumber) GetType() Person_PhoneType {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Type
    }
    return Person_MOBILE
}

type AddressBook struct {
    People               []*Person `protobuf:"bytes,1,rep,name=people,proto3" json:"people,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{}  `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte    `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32     `json:"-"`
}

func (m *AddressBook) Reset()         { *m = AddressBook{} }
func (m *AddressBook) String() string { return proto.CompactTextString(m) }
func (*AddressBook) ProtoMessage()    {}
func (*AddressBook) Descriptor() ([]byte, []int) {
    return fileDescriptor_1eb1a68c9dd6d429, []int{1}
}

func (m *AddressBook) XXX_Unmarshal(b []byte) error {
    return xxx_messageInfo_AddressBook.Unmarshal(m, b)
}
func (m *AddressBook) XXX_Marshal(b []byte, deterministic bool) ([]byte, error) {
    return xxx_messageInfo_AddressBook.Marshal(b, m, deterministic)
}
func (m *AddressBook) XXX_Merge(src proto.Message) {
    xxx_messageInfo_AddressBook.Merge(m, src)
}
func (m *AddressBook) XXX_Size() int {
    return xxx_messageInfo_AddressBook.Size(m)
}
func (m *AddressBook) XXX_DiscardUnknown() {
    xxx_messageInfo_AddressBook.DiscardUnknown(m)
}

var xxx_messageInfo_AddressBook proto.InternalMessageInfo

func (m *AddressBook) GetPeople() []*Person {
    if m != nil {
        return m.People
    }
    return nil
}

func init() {
    proto.RegisterEnum("addressbook.Person_PhoneType", Person_PhoneType_name, Person_PhoneType_value)
    proto.RegisterType((*Person)(nil), "addressbook.Person")
    proto.RegisterType((*Person_PhoneNumber)(nil), "addressbook.Person.PhoneNumber")
    proto.RegisterType((*AddressBook)(nil), "addressbook.AddressBook")
}

func init() { proto.RegisterFile("addressbook.proto", fileDescriptor_1eb1a68c9dd6d429) }

var fileDescriptor_1eb1a68c9dd6d429 = []byte{
    // 309 bytes of a gzipped FileDescriptorProto
    0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xff, 0x74, 0x90, 0x41, 0x4b, 0xc3, 0x40,
    0x10, 0x85, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x06, 0x3b, 0x91, 0x52, 0x47, 0x91, 0x50, 0x90, 0x86, 0x9e, 0x02, 0x85,
    0x14, 0xeb, 0x41, 0x10, 0x3c, 0x58, 0x28, 0x28, 0x5a, 0x5b, 0x96, 0x8a, 0xde, 0x24, 0x21, 0x63,
    0x0d, 0x4d, 0xb2, 0x4b, 0x76, 0x7b, 0xe8, 0xcf, 0xf3, 0x9f, 0x49, 0x76, 0x53, 0xe9, 0x41, 0x6f,
    0x6f, 0x66, 0x3f, 0xde, 0xbe, 0x37, 0x70, 0x1a, 0xa7, 0x69, 0x45, 0x52, 0x26, 0x9c, 0x6f, 0x22,
    0x51, 0x71, 0xc5, 0xd1, 0x3b, 0x58, 0xf5, 0x07, 0x6b, 0xce, 0xd7, 0x39, 0x8d, 0xf5, 0x53, 0xb2,
    0xfd, 0x1c, 0xab, 0xac, 0x20, 0xa9, 0xe2, 0x42, 0x18, 0x7a, 0xf8, 0x6d, 0x83, 0xbb, 0xa4, 0x4a,
    0xf2, 0x12, 0x11, 0x9c, 0x32, 0x2e, 0xc8, 0xb7, 0x02, 0x2b, 0xec, 0x30, 0xad, 0xb1, 0x0b, 0x76,
    0x96, 0xfa, 0x76, 0x60, 0x85, 0x6d, 0x66, 0x67, 0x29, 0x9e, 0x43, 0x9b, 0x8a, 0x38, 0xcb, 0xfd,
    0x96, 0x86, 0xcc, 0x80, 0x37, 0xe0, 0x8a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0x92, 0xf4, 0x9d, 0xa0, 0x15, 0x7a, 0x93,
    0x41, 0x74, 0x18, 0xcb, 0xd8, 0x47, 0xcb, 0x9a, 0x78, 0xd9, 0x16, 0x09, 0x55, 0xac, 0xc1, 0xf1,
    0x0e, 0x4e, 0xf2, 0x58, 0xaa, 0x8f, 0xad, 0x48, 0x63, 0x45, 0xa9, 0xdf, 0x0e, 0xac, 0xd0, 0x9b,
    0xf4, 0x23, 0x93, 0x3a, 0xda, 0xa7, 0x8e, 0x56, 0xfb, 0xd4, 0xcc, 0xab, 0xf9, 0x57, 0x83, 0xf7,
    0xdf, 0xc1, 0x3b, 0x70, 0xc5, 0x0b, 0x70, 0x4b, 0xad, 0x9a, 0x0a, 0xcd, 0x84, 0x57, 0xe0, 0xa8,
    0x9d, 0x20, 0x5d, 0xa3, 0x3b, 0xb9, 0xfc, 0x37, 0xdc, 0x6a, 0x27, 0x88, 0x69, 0x74, 0x38, 0x82,
    0xce, 0xef, 0x0a, 0x01, 0xdc, 0xf9, 0x62, 0xfa, 0xf8, 0x3c, 0xeb, 0x1d, 0xe1, 0x31, 0x38, 0x0f,
    0x8b, 0xf9, 0xac, 0x67, 0xd5, 0xea, 0x6d, 0xc1, 0x9e, 0x7a, 0xf6, 0xf0, 0x16, 0xbc, 0x7b, 0x63,
    0x39, 0xe5, 0x7c, 0x83, 0x23, 0x70, 0x05, 0x71, 0x91, 0xd7, 0x97, 0xac, 0xaf, 0x71, 0xf6, 0xc7,
    0x87, 0xac, 0x41, 0x12, 0x57, 0x77, 0xbc, 0xfe, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x9a, 0x92, 0x62,
    0x76, 0xc9, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00,
}
```

I'm trying this script in `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto"
    "github.com/kurtpeek/addressbook/addressbook"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
    person := addressbook.Person{
        Name:  "Boba Fett",
        Email: "boba.fett@gmail.com",
        Phones: []*addressbook.Person_PhoneNumber{
            &addressbook.Person_PhoneNumber{
                Number: "4158666171",
                Type:   addressbook.Person_MOBILE,
            },
        },
    }
    book := addressbook.AddressBook{
        People: []*addressbook.Person{&person},
    }

    _, err := proto.Marshal(book)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.WithError(err).Fatal("marshal to ProtoBuf")
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", person)
}
```

The problem is that when I try to run this I get an error that `AddressBook` doesn't implement the `Message` interface:

```
> go run main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:26:25: cannot use book (type addressbook.AddressBook) as type "github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto".Message in argument to "github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto".Marshal:
    addressbook.AddressBook does not implement "github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto".Message (ProtoMessage method has pointer receiver)
```

Going to the definition of a `Message`, I find the following interface:

```
// Message is implemented by generated protocol buffer messages.
type Message interface {
    Reset()
    String() string
    ProtoMessage()
}
```

It seems from the `addressbook.pg.go` that `AddressBook` implements all three of these methods, so I don't get why I'm getting the error message?

Here is my `go.mod`,

```
module github.com/kurtpeek/addressbook

go 1.12

require (
    github.com/gogo/protobuf v1.3.1
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.2
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.4.2
)
```

and here is my `protoc` version (I installed `protoc` using `brew install protobuf`):

```
> protoc --version
libprotoc 3.11.1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a pointer to proto.Marshal() either do `proto.Marshal(&book)` or create pointer already before when you create the book like this:

```
book := &addressbook.AddressBook{
             People: []*addressbook.Person{&person},
        }
```

see the & in the first line

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem from API version.

[From the go blog](https://blog.golang.org/protobuf-apiv2)

> The github.com/golang/protobuf module is APIv1. The google.golang.org/protobuf module is APIv2. We have taken advantage of the need to change the import path to switch to one that is not tied to a specific hosting provider. (We considered google.golang.org/protobuf/v2, to make it clear that this is the second major version of the API, but settled on the shorter path as being the better choice in the long term.)

Therefore, to run your code simply, use "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto" instead of "github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto" for marshal function. The problem is from a new api protoreflect. See article.

You have an option to use "google.golang.org/protobuf" but my suggestion is to use "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto". You can read more about the difference of the two [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go/faq).